# Ansible copy module with {{ item }}

Tags: copy, ansible

I have a yml file for variables which goes like this.

```
- newHosts     
   - hostIP: 192.168.1.22
     filename: file1 
   - hostIP: 192.168.1.23   
     filename: file2
```

I am using add_host: {{ item.hostIP }} with_items {{ newHosts }}.
I want to copy respective file to respective hosts with something like {{ item.filename }} but it copies all files to each host. How I just copy only the corresponding file to the node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditionals that are applied at each iteration of the loop for example:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: copy file to appropriate server
    copy: src={{item.filename}} dest=/var/foo/{{item.filename}}
    with_items: newHosts
    when: item.hostIP == ansible_ssh_host
```